# Filter elements in Revit and set parameter

Tags: c#, revit-api, revit

Hello everybody, 

around two or three month ago I started to learn Dynamo for Revit... finally :)

After learning and testing a lot, I got a few own scripts working. Then I learned Python, because I couldn't create the next script only with Dynamo-Nodes.

Then I thought "Let's see how difficult it is to get something done as a PlugIn".
I watched some Videos and read a lot of stuff. 
Finally I got the Revit-AddIn-Wizard installed and made my first small Test-PlugIn.
Great...

Now I have a few problems which I do not understand... so I thought I will try my luck here... because I got so much information and help, reading through this site.

My goal was/is the following: (I tell you what I have now)
A form with a few buttons, comboboxes and a DataGridView.
I can load an Excelfile, click on "Show" to show it in the DataGridView.
The header of each row will be automatically put into 3 comboboxes.
In the first combobox you select the first search-parameter, in the second you CAN select another search-parameter and in the third combobox you select the parameter you want to set.
I have a checkbox to switch from type- to instance-parameter for the search- and the set-operation.
There is also a button which shows another small form with a list of categories (I won't search for ALL, only nearly all modelcategories).

[PlugIn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhlkU.jpg)

I took me a lot of "watching Videos, reading through the internet, testing, testing and testing".
Thanks to this site here and a few others... I managed to get this whole PlugIn nearly 100% working.

But now I have a few strange issues and I have absolutely no clue on how to fix them or if it is possible. And I really hope that someone can help me.

First... I just tell you my problems and perhaps someone can say "this really IS an issue!" or that it is possible to get it done. Then I would post some code.

So... what do I do?!
1. I have a FilteredElementCollector which filters ALL elements.
2. Depending on my "Type/Instance-Checkboxes" I do .WhereElementIsElementType OR .WhereElementIsNotElementType.
3. Then it passes a MultiCategoryFilter to get the big list down to only the modelcategories.
4. Next, the collection passes one of ten different "methods" depending on all settings. There I filter this collection depending on the searchlists-comboboxes. When the combobox says "Familie" or "Typ" then it filters for ".BuiltInParameter.SymbolFamilyName" or ".Name" otherwise it just uses ".LookupParameter".

After that I have a collection with only the elements of selected categories which contains the values from the Excellist.

5. Depending on what my search- and set-settings are (e.g. search for type and set instance) I have to get the instances from the collected types or the other way around.
6. Then I pass it down to another method where I finally set the parameter.

So... Excelheader goes into comboboxes, depending on what you select in there it creates lists with the values of the selected rows. 
I hope you all understand.

Now... where are my problems?
When I search for type-familynames or instance-parameter and set a typeparameter it works for ALL categories without any error.

1. When I try to set an instanceparameter (doesn't matter what my search-setting are) it works for all "normal" families but not for the systemfamilies (e.g. walls, floors, pipes etc.). No error, just nothing happens   WHY? It seems that I cannot set an instance-parameter for system-families.

2. Roofs, Stairs, CurtainPanels and GenericModel make problems when I search for a typeparameter Error is something like "The object reference was not set to an object instance". Only with these 4 categories and it doesn't matter what I want to set... but when I search for family-/typeNAME or Instance-Parameter, then I can set type or instance and it works (except instance for sysfam).

3. When I try to search AND set an instance-parameter it works for ALL categories EXCEPT if one wall does not contain a search value... it really is enough that ONE wall does not have a search-param-value that everything will be cancelled.

I have a few other small problems... but I hope someone can help me with these problems... I would be extremely thankfull

greetings and have a nice day or night :)
Philipp

Answer (score 0):

Tl; dr.

The three problems you describe sound like your own. I have no heard anybody else runAsk three separate questions and provide three separate minimal code snippets describing how they arise,.  into those. I suggest that you create three separate independent [minimal reproducible cases](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/about-the-author.html#1b) to demonstrate all three issues. Chances are, when you simplify and minimalise your code, the problem will go away. If it does not, it might just possibly be in a small and manageable enough state for other people to help you take a look at it. Given the long-winded description above, nobody in the world can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer Jeremy,

as I said, as a first start it is ok for me if you don't say "With theses categories, there are indeed some issues!"

I think I've managed to create 3 small examples of my problems.
For each problem I made a zip-file containing the complete visual-studio folder, a small exampleproject and a readme.txt with (I hope) enough information to understand everything in detail.

[Problem1](https://www.arch-e-motion.de/downloads/SearchType.zip)

[Problem3](https://www.arch-e-motion.de/downloads/SetInstance2.zip)

You only need to compile them or copy the .addin and .ddl files into the Revit AddIn folder. Then you get the new ribbons.

Short problem summary = I get problems when searching for parametervalues and setting values to another parameter.

Edit: I just solved the 2. problem when searching for familynames and setting system-families-parameter.
I used:

```
ElementClassFilter ecf = new ElementClassFilter(typeof(FamilyInstance));    
FilteredElementColletor colle2 = new FilteredElementCollector(doc);
colle2.WherePasses(ecf);
```

I simply deleted the ClassFilter and do it now like in the other cases where I need instances.

```
FilteredElementCollector colle2 = new FilteredElementCollector(doc);
colle2.WhereElementIsNotElementType();
```

The 1. and 3. problem still exist :/

I would be thankful for any help someone can provide :)